# logical operations for ending a game Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, logic

I seem to be having some type of problem getting into the winning logical operations of my Javascript/J Query hangman game and I don't know what the problem is really (the loosing part of my game seems to be working fine if the player looses, it's just the winning part- if u win, sometimes the game shows the winning image&css but sometimes it does nothing and don't know why- it seems to work the longer I play/with longer words and I'm not sure why or what is going on /why it would work sometimes and not all the time or what the slip in logic is that makes it not function.

Here's my code for the keyboard control & endGame() function:

```
$(".form-control").keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == 13) {
      var space = $(this).val();
      play(space);
      $(this).val('');
      endGame();
      return false;
    }
  });
function endGame() {
    if (wrongGuesses.length >= 10) {
      $("body").css("background-color", "#ff4500");
      $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
      console.log(rightGuesses);
      console.log(word);
    } else if (rightGuesses.length == word.length && wrongGuesses.length < 10)         {
      $(images[i]).hide();
      $("#victory").show();
      $("body").css("background-color", "#8AFBFF" );
      $("body").animate( { backgroundColor: "#0C0D86" }, 2000 );
      $("body").animate( { backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 2000 );
    }
}
```

And here's my entire game code:

```
var wordBank = ["modernism", "situationalist", "sartre", "camus", "hegel", "lacan", "barthes", "baudrillard", "foucault", "debord", "baudrillard"];
var word = [];
var wrongGuesses = [];
var rightGuesses = [];
var images = [gallows, head, body, armL, handL, armR, handR, legL, footL, legR, footR];
var y = 0;
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  function randomWord() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordBank.length);
    var toString = wordBank[random];
    console.log(toString);
    word = toString.split("");
    console.log(word);
  }
  randomWord();

  function wordSpaces() {
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      $(".word-spaces > tbody > tr").append('<td data-idx=i>' + word[i] + '</td>')
    }
  }
  wordSpaces();

  function play(space) {
    //indexOf()==inArray() 
    var lIndex = jQuery.inArray(space, word);
    console.log(lIndex);
    if (lIndex == -1) {
      wrongGuesses.push(space);
      var wrong = wrongGuesses.length;
      console.log('wrong ' + wrong);
      $('.wrongLetters tbody tr td:nth-of-type(' + wrong + ')').text(space);

//      $(this).css("background-color", "#ff4500").fadeIn(300).delay(800).fadeOut(300);
      $(images[i - 1]).hide();
      $(images[i]).show();
      i++;
      $("html").css("background-color", "#ff4500").fadeIn(300).delay(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(100);
      console.log(word);
    } else { 
      console.log(word + "word"); 
      console.log(space + "space");
        function getInstances(word,space) {
       //   var string = word[0]; 
      //    console.log(string);
      //    var splitArray=string.split("");
      //    console.log(splitArray);
          var indexes = [], w;
          for(w=0; w<word.length;w++ )
          if (word[w] === space)
          indexes.push(w);
          return indexes;
        }
      console.log(word + "word"); 
      console.log(space + "space");
      var indexes = getInstances(word, space);
      console.log(indexes);
  //    rightGuesses.push(space);
      console.log(rightGuesses); 
  //    var right = rightGuesses.length;
      indexes.forEach(function (index){
      $(".word-spaces tbody tr td:nth-of-type(" + (index + 1) + ")").css('color', 'black');
      });
      rightGuesses.push(space);
  //    rightGuesses.push(space);

    }
  }

  $(".form-control").keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == 13) {
      var space = $(this).val();
      play(space);
      $(this).val('');
      endGame();
      return false;
    }
  });

/*
  function endGame() {
    if (wrongGuesses.length >= 10 || rightGuesses.length == word.length) {
      $("body").css("background-color", "#ff4500");
      $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
    if (rightGuesses.length == word.length){

    }
    } }


*/
function endGame() {
    if (wrongGuesses.length >= 10) {
      $("body").css("background-color", "#ff4500");
      $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
      console.log(rightGuesses);
      console.log(word);
    } else if (rightGuesses.length == word.length && wrongGuesses.length < 10)     {
      $(images[i]).hide();
      $("#victory").show();
      $("body").css("background-color", "#8AFBFF" );
      $("body").animate( { backgroundColor: "#0C0D86" }, 2000 );
      $("body").animate( { backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 2000 );
    }
}


});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated- I feel like I've been working on this game for so long that I'm just not seeing things anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out like this: first I created another empty array global variable: var right = []; then I set up another .forEach loop to count the number of right letters (to take into account the count of multiple letters) - indexes.forEach(function(index) {
        //      answer[index] = space;
        rightCount++
      })
and then I pushed these values into the empty array:
 right.push(rightCount);
then I sorted this array to get the sum to use in the later logical operation:
function endGame() {
    var sumRight = right.reduce(add, 0);

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
if (sumRight == word.length) {
  $(images[i]).hide();
  $("#victory").show();
  $("body").css("background-color", "#8AFBFF");
  $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
  $("body").animate({
    backgroundColor: "#0C0D86"
  }, 2000);
  $("body").animate({
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  }, 2000);
} else if (wrongGuesses.length >= 10) {
  $("body").css("background-color", "#ff4500");
  $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
  $("body").animate({
    backgroundColor: "#000000"
  }, 2000);
  $("body").animate({
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  }, 2000);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're checking `rightGuesses.length == word.length`

If a word has multiple of the same letter, I can complete the word with less guesses than the word.length.

I was able to troubleshoot this by modifying your end game and hitting control+shift+i to view the console.

```
function endGame() {
  console.log(wrongGuesses.length, rightGuesses.length, word.length);
    if (wrongGuesses.length >= 10 || rightGuesses.length == word.length) {
      $("body").css("background-color", "#ff4500");
      $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
```

Updated Fiddle to capture the answer and compare it to the original word:
https://jsfiddle.net/8cgx2sfd/4/

```
var wordBank = [ "marka"];
var word = [];
var answer = [];
var wrongGuesses = [];
var rightGuesses = [];
var images = [gallows, head, body, armL, handL, armR, handR, legL, footL, legR, footR];
var y = 0;
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  function randomWord() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordBank.length);
    var toString = wordBank[random];
    console.log(toString);
    word = toString.split("");
    console.log(word);
  }
  randomWord();

  function wordSpaces() {
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      $(".word-spaces > tbody > tr").append('<td data-idx=i>' + word[i] + '</td>')
    }
  }
  wordSpaces();

  function play(space) {
    //indexOf()==inArray() 
    var lIndex = jQuery.inArray(space, word);
    console.log(lIndex);
    if (lIndex == -1) {
      wrongGuesses.push(space);
      var wrong = wrongGuesses.length;
      console.log('wrong ' + wrong);
      $('.wrongLetters tbody tr td:nth-of-type(' + wrong + ')').text(space);

//      $(this).css("background-color", "#ff4500").fadeIn(300).delay(800).fadeOut(300);
      $(images[i - 1]).hide();
      $(images[i]).show();
      i++;
      $("html").css("background-color", "#ff4500").fadeIn(300).delay(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(100);
      console.log(word);
    } else { 
      console.log(word + "word"); 
      console.log(space + "space");
        function getInstances(word,space) {
       //   var string = word[0]; 
      //    console.log(string);
      //    var splitArray=string.split("");
      //    console.log(splitArray);
          var indexes = [], w;
          for(w=0; w<word.length;w++ )
          if (word[w] === space)
          indexes.push(w);

          return indexes;
        }
      console.log(word + "word"); 
      console.log(space + "space");
      var indexes = getInstances(word, space);
      console.log("indexes", indexes);
      indexes.forEach(function(index){
        answer[index] = space;
      });

      console.log("answer", answer);
  //    rightGuesses.push(space);
      console.log(rightGuesses); 
  //    var right = rightGuesses.length;
      indexes.forEach(function (index){
      $(".word-spaces tbody tr td:nth-of-type(" + (index + 1) + ")").css('color', 'black');
      });
      rightGuesses.push(space);
  //    rightGuesses.push(space);

    }
  }

  $(".form-control").keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == 13) {
      var space = $(this).val();
      play(space);
      $(this).val('');
      endGame();
      return false;
    }
  });


  function endGame() {
   console.log(wrongGuesses.length, rightGuesses.length, word.length, (word===answer), word, answer);
   var diff = $(answer).not(word).get();
   console.log('diff', diff);
    if (wrongGuesses.length >= 10 || rightGuesses.length == word.length || answer === word) {
      $("body").css("background-color", "#ff4500");
      $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
    }

  }

});
```

Comment: I see what u mean, @mkaatman - now I have to devise a logical operation to see if they won that's not based just on if the rightGuesses.legnth == word.length (originally, I had this exact same function 2 end my game but I was told I had 2 show different scenarios for winning & loosing for this assignment so was trying to change it)- now I need 2 come up w/a different logical operation to test if they've won... Thanks!

Comment: That's why Sometimes it was going into the winning dialogue- bc Sometimes, those conditions Were being met, just not Always (That's the part that was Rlly confusing me too bc when it works Sometimes, u wonder what is going on)- cool, thanks, I feel like I need to examine this a bit closer now, I don't know why this game has given me so much trouble ;-) but it has

Comment: hey @mkaatman- Thank u- actually, what u did helped me alot solve this problem my original way by simplifying it to one word & seeing some of your logic- what I did was this: I created a new empty array then I created a count that I added to on every forEach loop through, then I pushed that value into the empty array. Then at the end, I reduced that array of values to get a total count of rights that I could then do a correct logical operation with(i know it's complicated but at least it's accurate)...

Comment: Thank You so much- sometimes it just helps so much to get some assistance & see how someone else would go about solving a problem - now my victory animation is working, it's all working! Thanks @mkaatman - this helped me so much & made me feel less alone & stuck through this process- Thanks!

Comment: Good job. You might want to post your final solution as an answer and accept it in case others find this in the future.